# Using case class benefits through inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

I would like to use some `case class` features like the following:

```
val base: Base = new Derived
println(base.copy())
```

I cannot define both `Base` and `Derived` as case classes. And making any of them case class raises compiler error: `Cannot resolve symbol copy`.
So, there is a workaround with dispatching case class metods to children:

```
abstract class BaseWorkaround(name: String) {
  def dispatchCopy: BaseWorkaround
}
case class DerivedWorkaround(name: String) extends BaseWorkaround(name) {
  override def dispatchCopy: BaseWorkaround = copy()
}

val abbie: BaseWorkaround = DerivedWorkaround("Abbie")
println(abbie.dispatchCopy)
```

The workaround works, but looks cumbersome. Is there more elegant way to perform this behaviour?

Comment: What you want would not work as expected anyways: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, you cannot inherit a `copy` because base class' `copy` method wouldn't know how to copy subclass' fields.

What you are doing works, but, if you think about it, it is rather useless: case classes are (or, should be by design) immutable, so, if `foo` is an instance of a case class, then `foo` and `foo.copy()` are pretty much *the same object* for all practical purposes, creating these copies instead of just using `foo` everywhere is just pure waste of memory. (You can also just use `clone` instead of copy, if that's what you are really looking for for some reason - just make `Base` extend `Cloneable`)

The reason `copy` exists, if *because it actually takes parameters* (the actual definition of `Derived.copy` is `def copy(name: String = name)`) to facilitate creating instances of the class that are *different* from the original, i.e.: `val foo = Derived("foo"); val bar = foo.copy("bar")` ...

So, if you know what parameters your case classes will have, you can do something like this:

```
abstract class Base[T <: Base] { 
  def name: String; 
  def copy(name: String = name): T
}

case class Derived1(name: String) extends Base[Derived1]
case class Derived2(name: String) extends Base[Derived2]

val p: Base[_] = Derived1("foo")
val pCopy = p.copy()
val s: Base[_] = Derived2("bar")
val sCopy = s.copy
```

Note, that `Derived1` and `Derived2` are almost the same thing though (both are really just a "glorified String"). While this may still be useful in some cases (e.g., define different kinds of application-specific errors with a detailed message), the major limitation of this approach is that you cannot define subclasses with different set of parameters than you have defined in `Base`:

```
// This won't compile:
class Derived3(name: String, code: Int) extends Base[Derived3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the information why inheritance of case classes is bad and what possible workarounds are:

[Scala case class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705309/scala-case-class-inheritance)

[Extend case class from another case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986931/extend-case-class-from-another-case-class)

[Should I use the final modifier when declaring case classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561614/should-i-use-the-final-modifier-when-declaring-case-classes)

[case class inheriting another class/trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345223/case-class-inheriting-another-class-trait)

[What is *so* wrong with case class inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158929/what-is-so-wrong-with-case-class-inheritance)

[Inheriting properties among case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360001/inheriting-properties-among-case-class)

Case classes are intended for algebraic data types in functional programming:

```
sealed trait Base
case class Derived1(i: Int) extends Base
case class Derived2(s: String) extends Base
```

OOP and inheritance with them are weird.
You should prefer composition over inheritance:

```
case class Base(s: String)
case class Derived(i: Int, b: Base)
```

There are alternatives to case classes:

- Contraband code generation

http://eed3si9n.com/contraband-an-alternative-to-case-class/

https://www.scala-sbt.org/contraband/

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Datatype.html (sbt-datatype)

https://github.com/sbt/contraband

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/5xu085/contraband_an_alternative_to_case_class/

- Stalagmite `@data`

https://gitlab.com/fommil/attic/tree/master/stalagmite

- Data-class `@data`

https://github.com/alexarchambault/data-class

- [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) `@data`, `@root`/`@branch`/`@leaf`, `@root`/`@branch`/`@ast`

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.7.5/scalameta/common/shared/src/main/scala/org/scalameta/data/data.scala#L9-L21

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.7.5/scalameta/common/shared/src/main/scala/org/scalameta/adt/Adt.scala#L11-L19

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.7.5/scalameta/common/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/trees/root.scala#L11

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.7.5/scalameta/common/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/trees/branch.scala#L11

https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/blob/v4.7.5/scalameta/common/shared/src/main/scala/scala/meta/internal/trees/ast.scala#L13

- generation of methods `apply/unapply`, `copy` etc. with [macro-annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

[Generate apply methods creating a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61949890/)

[how to efficiently/cleanly override a copy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514436/)

[Prohibit generating of apply for case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453378/)

- generic derivation with type classes

https://svejcar.dev/posts/2019/09/26/better-tostring-alternative-for-case-classes/

- [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) case classes a la carte

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/alacarte.scala

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/shared/src/test/scala/shapeless/alacarte.scala

---

Let's think what signature `copy` in `Base` should have. My understanding is that you meant

```
sealed trait Base {
  type This <: Base
  def name: String
  def age: Int
  def copy(name: String = name, age: Int = age): This
}
case class Derived(name: String, age: Int) extends Base {
  override type This = Derived
  override def copy(name: String = name, age: Int = age): Derived = Derived(name, age)
}
```

or

```
sealed trait Base {
  def name: String
  def age: Int
  def copy(name: String = name, age: Int = age): Base
}
case class Derived(name: String, age: Int) extends Base {
  override def copy(name: String = name, age: Int = age): Derived = Derived(name, age)
}
```

In principle, `def copy` in `Derived`, `def copy` in `Base`, `def name`, `def age` in Base can be generated from `case class Derived(name: String, age: Int)`. But what if there are several inheritors of `Base`? Doesn't `Base` know too much now about `Derived`?